# How to use MCMC / gibbs sampling instead of an optimization algorithm ?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, optimization, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process

I've tried and implementend Factorization Machines with different loss functions and optimization algorithms (SGD , coordinate descent, adagrad, adadelta ...) and I've seen that it's possible to use MCMC too.

I didn't know what it meant at first and no pseudo-code was given in Rendle's article. So I tried to discover what it is, Markov Chains aren't complete strangers to me since I've taken a Stochastic processes course but even if I understood the core idea of MCMC, I still don't understand how I can use it to learn a predictive model's parameters.

Can anyone guide me and/or give some good references to me in that regard ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps you could post a link or reference to the article you refer to in the post?